# how to get RTTI from member function pointers

Tags: c++, c++17, rtti, pointer-to-member

I'm trying to add logging to some legacy code that invokes one of many member function pointers. Would like to print the name of the member function before we call it. This is just for debugging (using C++17) and it doesn't have to be portable or standard C++ (a gcc extension would be fine). Tried using typeinfo like below but it only shows the class (not the actual member function).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

class myclass
{
public:
 void foo() { }
};

int main()
{
    auto x = &myclass::foo;    
    std::cout << typeid(x).name() << "\n";
}
```

There's a very clever trick on elsewhere on stack overflow where you use templates to populate an `std::map` with function pointers and their names (which you get from `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`) but it doesn't work with *member* function pointers because (as far as I can tell) member function pointers can't be saved in a container.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Member function pointers can be saved in a container just fine.

Comment: @user17732522 as far as I know `typeid(int)` works and there's no dynamic types involved

Comment: Correction of my previous comment: `x` is a not a polymorphic type and therefore the `typeid` result will not depent on the pointer's value at runtime.

Comment: Would having a *pointer to a member function pointer* work for your use case?  `auto xx = &x;` and `std::cout <<typeid(xx).name() << "\n";`

Comment: The type of `&myclass::foo` doesn't include the name `foo` (no more than the type of `&x` in `int x` includes the name `x`). Consider: if `myclass` had another member `void bar();`, then `&myclass::foo` and `&myclass::bar` would have the same type, namely `void (myclass::*)()`

Comment: thanks @IgorTandetnik, this explains the behavior. I found a fix for the original issue (logging the names of member functions)... you can actually extract the function pointer from a member function pointer and then use that as an index into a container with the function names. Each function has to be registered manually, but it works.